# Handling exceptions in a ViewModel without a View (in ReactiveUI)

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, mvvm, reactiveui

I am currently building an application in C# using ReactiveUI that contains many views/viewmodels. Some of these viewmodels perform a network request at a preset interval. These network requests may fail at any time. I implemented this as follows:

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, IReactiveList<IJob>> RefreshJobList { get; }
public Interaction<Exception, Unit> RefreshError { get; } = new Interaction<Exception, Unit>();

...

RefreshJobList = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(() => DoNetworkRequest());
RefreshJobList.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex =>
{
    log.Error("Failed to retrieve job list from server.", ex);
    RefreshError.Handle(ex).Subscribe();
});
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)).Select(x => Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(RefreshJobList);
```

In the corresponding views, I handle the exceptions as follows:

```
this.WhenActivated(d => d(
    this.ViewModel.RefreshError.RegisterHandler(interaction =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to load joblist.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        interaction.SetOutput(new Unit());
    })
));
```

This works fine, except when the viewmodel isn't associated with a view. My application uses tabs, and when the user switches to a different tab, the previous view is destroyed. This leaves the viewmodel running, still making requests, without a view. Then, when an error occurs in `RefreshJobList`, no handlers are associated with `RefreshError`, ReactiveUI throws an `UnhandledInteractionError` and my application crashes.

I am not sure how to deal with this cleanly. My first thought would be to pause the ViewModel until a View is attached, which would also save network traffic. However, I can't seem any way to check whether or not a View is attached to the ViewModel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the solution was using `WhenActivated`, supplied by `ISupportsActivation` on the ViewModel.

I am now using the following code in de viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
    public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; } = new ViewModelActivator();

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, IReactiveList<IJob>> RefreshJobList { get; }
    public Interaction<Exception, Unit> RefreshError { get; } = new Interaction<Exception, Unit>();

    ...

    public ViewModel(){
        RefreshJobList = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(() => DoNetworkRequest());
        RefreshJobList.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex =>
        {
            log.Error("Failed to retrieve job list from server.", ex);
            RefreshError.Handle(ex).Subscribe();
        });
        this.WhenActivated(d => d(
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)).Select(x => Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(RefreshJobList)
        ));
    }
}
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, just out of curiosity, why there is .Subscribe() in the handler calling code  `RefreshError.Handle(ex).Subscribe();`? Wouldn't it work the same without it?

Comment: .Handle() returns a cold observable. Cold observables need to be used with .Subscribe or await to get invoked. (Researching this was pretty confusing, maybe this should be in the documentation?)

Answer (score 3):

If your view implements `IViewFor` and you view model implements `ISupportsActivation` you can dispose the subscription to `ThrownExceptions` when navigating away from the view:

```
// In your VM

this.WhenActivated(d=>
{
    RefreshJobList
        .ThrownExceptions
        .Do(ex => log.Error("Failed to retrieve job list from server.", ex))
        .SelectMany(ex => RefreshError.Handle(ex))
        .Subscribe()
        .DisposeWith(d); // This will dispose of the subscription when the view model is deactivated
});
```

This will make the `ReactiveCommand` throw an exception if an exception occurs when the view model is not active. To get around that you could either stop the running operation when deactivating the view model. Alternatively you could catch the exception as jamie suggested: `RefreshError.Handle(ex).Catch(ex => Observable.Empty<Exception>())`

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the WhenActivated extension in your view model to 'stop' / dispose of observables that should no longer be in play when the view is disposed?

I believe you can always catch the exception from the Interaction being handled in the Subscribe, just add an OnError handler.

Comment: I had been looking for WhenActivated, but assumed it wasn't supported because ReactiveObject doesn't supply it. However, I just found ISupportsActivation which adds WhenActivated and solves the problem. :)